# Spree Commerce Vendors Listing Page [NoMethodError : undefined method `each' for #<Class:...>]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, model-view-controller, spree

I'm creating a view that list all vendors using [**Spree Multi Vendor**](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_multi_vendor) extension for [**Spree Commerce**](https://github.com/spree/spree).

My `index.html.erb` template :

```
<% @vendors.each do |vendor| %>
    <h2>
      <%= vendor.name %>
    </h2>
<% end %>
```

My `stores_controller.rb` controller :

```
module Spree
    class StoresController < Spree::StoreController  
      def index
        @vendors = Spree::Vendor
      end
    end
end
```

The error that I'm getting :

> NoMethodError in Spree::Stores#index
>
> Showing /myapp/app/views/spree/stores/index.html.erb where line #36
>   raised:
>
> undefined method `each' for # < Class:0x00007fe3f5570a40 >
>
> Line #36 : <% @vendors.each do |vendor| %>

How can I correctly instantiate [`Vendor Model`](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_multi_vendor/blob/master/app/models/spree/vendor.rb) inside my controller so I can use it's methods and access it's attributes in the views of my store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spree::Vendor` is just a model class. You can think about it like any other model - `User`, `Product`, etc.

In this case, you should call `Spree::Vendor.all` or `Spree::Vendor.active` to fetch records.

Comment: Thanks man ! Do you have any idea for how to get a vendor object by extracting it's name from the url ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56766442/single-vendor-page-route-and-controller-for-spree-commerce