# Load Vendor Object By Name Parameter Extracted From The URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, model-view-controller, spree

I'm trying to create a route that link to the store page of each [Vendor](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_multi_vendor/blob/master/app/models/spree/vendor.rb) using [Spree Commerce](https://github.com/spree/spree). The page should list the details (name, about us, etc), and the products of the given vendor.

```
https://example.com/stores/vendor-one
```

My ***routes.rb*** configuration :

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
    resources :stores
end
```

My ***stores_controller*** controller :

```
module Spree
    class StoresController < Spree::StoreController  
      require 'vendor'
      def show
        @vendor = current_spree_vendor
      end     
    end
end
```

My ***show.html.erb*** template :

```
<h2><%= @vendor.name %></h2>
<p><%= @vendor.about_us %></p>
```

The error that I'm getting :

> NoMethodError in Spree::Stores#single
>
> Showing /myapp/app/views/spree/stores/show.html.erb where line #2 raised:
>
> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
>
> Line # 2 : `<h2><%= @vendor.name %></h2>`

How can I load the given [**Vendor**](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_multi_vendor/blob/master/app/models/spree/vendor.rb) by getting its name from the url ? I'm new to Rails so any help will be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to debug errors like this is by working backwards from the error.  The error is occurring in the template because `@vendor` is `nil`.  Why?  The controller has a #show method that is setting `@vendor`, but it is setting @vendor to the result of `current_spree_vendor`, so it must be that `current_spree_vendor` returned `nil`.  So now you need to examine `current_spree_vendor` and figure out why it is sometimes returning nil.

You will soon learn how to debug this sort of error, and you'll need to because these kinds of errors are too common, and too specific, to be something that the internet can help you with.  Even when the internet can help, it's too slow and waiting for answers on it will keep you from getting the job done.

Comment: I just started with _RoR_. I've deeply examined `current_spree_vendor` [helper method](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_multi_vendor/blob/master/app/helpers/spree/admin/vendor_helper.rb) of [Multi Vendor Plugin](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_multi_vendor) and couldn't figure out why it's returning `nil`. How can I create a [_Vendor_ object](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_multi_vendor/blob/master/app/models/spree/vendor.rb) with the name extracted from the url?

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi I'm afraid that is too broad a question for me to answer, and probably too broad for SO.

Comment: I hope someone from Spree Community that is familiar with the pattern could help me with this. The solution is said to be "Open Source" but it lacks documentation and support... Very complicated to take things over control for new comers and I'm really stuck in this specific issue.

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi Open source does not mean "documented and supported."  I agree that RoR can be very confusing at times, and especially for a beginner.

Comment: Ok I was doing it all wrong. All I had to do to load the given vendor from the url is `@vendor = Vendor.friendly.find(params[:id])` inside the controller.

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi Outstanding!  Good job finding the solution.